# Injecting the validator service into a bundle

Tags: php, symfony

I'm learning Symfony2 at a new workplace and was tasked with adding validation to the code which is currently using poor inline based code instead of the Symfony validator and annotations.

I've added validation annotations to my model and added a parameter to my constructor. I've also added an argument to the service.yml so that it gets injected into my bundle's class, but it seems i cannot find the

```
@validator
```

as per described in the Symfony documentation (http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/validation.html). If i read the documentation right, i should be able to just add @validator to my services.yml and get it fed directly to my class but when running my tests, it says that the service @validator cannot be found:

```
The service "ugroup_media_personalization.flattening_service" 
has a dependency on a non-existent service "validator"
```

So what am i doing wrong here?

Comment: Very strange, check if the service is really loaded in the container launching  a command from shell: `php app/console container:debug | grep validator`

Comment: Nope, nothing returned... This is probably because i'm in a bundle? I know the guy talked about loading the kernel in the tests. I've opened in the AppKernel.php in the tests folder to make sure the validator bundle is in there, but i think it's part of the framework bundle which is already loaded

Comment: For a first, should @validator be the right service name? If not, what is the right service name in a service.yml file used to inject the validator service?

Comment: you are doing thing right! Something strange in your sf2 installation. is a standard version? The service you are looking for is defined in the frameworkbundle.

Comment: Problem found, i'll post a solution in a minute, the framework.validator configuration was not part of the bundle thus validations were not activated

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that the configuration file for the bundle did not specify the

```
framework:
    validation: {enable_annotations: true}
```

And thus the framework was not loading the validation service. You can simply use:

```
framework:
    validation:
```

if you want to trigger the loading the validation module, but in my case, i added enable_annotations to make sure the validation using annotations work!